# Problema con carga de datos Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Soy principaante en MVC 5 y estoy desarrollando una aplicación, tengo el siguiente problema, cuando cargo un `DropDownList` a veces carga nulo, no sé si tiene que ver con el flujo del código o si me falta inicializar en algún momento la base de datos, pero lo corrijo y carga bien, pero cuando cierro el visual o modifico algo en otro lado y vuelvo a cargar el proyecto me marca por `ViewData` que no existe el error y en `viewBag` que carga nulo.

Estoy haciendo una validación en el Controlador que si le faltan algunos datos me envíe a una vista para capturar esos datos en el `GET`.

```
public ActionResult Configure()...

var listaCargo = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var elem in mEncuesta.catCargo)
{
    listaCargo.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = elem.cargo,
        Value = elem.cveCargo.ToString()
    });
}

ViewData["cargo"] = listaCargo;
```

Código en el `ConfigureViewModel`:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe seleccionar un cargo")]
[Display(Name = "Seleccionar Cargo")]
public byte cveCargo { get; set; }
```

Y en la vista:

```
Html.DropDownList("cveCargo", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["cargo"], htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Lo corro y si la sesión está iniciada en caché, corre, pero si cierro el proyecto y lo vuelvo a abrir o si cierro sesión me marca el error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No hay ningún elemento ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable' con la clave 'cveCargo'.'

Si lo intento con `ViewBag` me marca que el valor es nulo.

Supongo que no es un error de código porque ya lo intenté con varias combinaciones y a veces sí jala, pero no detecto dónde esté el error de flujo.

Comment: Hola Silvia, bienvenida a [es.so]. Tengo algunas preguntas, ¿en qué `Action` del Controller se llena `mEncuesta.catCargo`? Si te das cuenta en el Controller asignas los datos a la variable `ViewData["cargo"]` pero en el View a `cveCargo`. Supongo que esas diferencias en los nombres de las variables ocasionan algún problema o falta que agregues más código. Si pudieras poner el código completo del Controller sería genial, así podemos ir descartando los lugares donde se encuentra la falla.